# Is it possible to register both persistent and non-persistent jobs using a single scheduler with quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

The quartz jobstore config is as follows which makes the job persistent.

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

I checked the api of job and trigger and didn't find any properties that can make a single job  non-persistent.
Would I have to use two different schedulers with 2 different sets of properties?